# Странное утверждение

Tags: этимология

В одной книге попалось утверждение, что слова "изба" и "самовар", этимология которого, вроде как, лежит на поверхности, на самом деле, тюркского происхождения. Насколько это может быть верно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Происхождение слова ИЗБА никак не тюркское.  Существует несколько объяснений его этимологии. Издавна известна гипотеза, что слово изба из праслав. *jьstьba первонач. значило «баня» > «отапливаемое примитивной печью помещение». Источником праслав.* jьstьba считается др.-в.-нем. stuba «теплое, отапливаемое помещение», «баня». Надо заметить, однако, что при этой этимологии трудно объяснить нач. гласный *и < jь*, 
который отмечается в слове уже с древнейшего периода. К тому же малоубедительна семант. сторона данной этимологии, т.к. в других слав. языках слово *изба* обозначает помещение для хранения имущества и продовольствия (ср. чеш. jizba, польск. izba, словацк. izba «комната, каморка, чулан»; болг. изба «хижина»; схв. изба «чулан»). Более вероятным представляется другое предположение, в соответствии с которым слово изба — в исходном значении «отапливаемое, теплое помещение» — проникло в рус. яз. не из герм., а из романских языков через южнославянские. Нар.-лат. *estuva — «теплая» было образовано от глаг. aestuare «отапливать», «делать теплым, жарким» (ср. лат. aestus «жар, зной»). Слову* estuva родственны: франц. etuve «парильня», «душное помещение»; исп. estuba «баня»; итал. диал. stua, stufe «комната с печью». В слав. языках сохранился нач. звук **и**. Он развился из jь-, который передавал гласн. **е** в начале лат. слова. Первонач. знач. отмечается только в рус. яз. В других слав. языках это знач. утратилось.

Что касается слова САМОВАР, то его этимология, действительно, лежит на поверхности: слово образовано от *сам* и *варить*. Некоторые исследователи видят в этом объяснении народную этимологию тюркского источника sanabar, но тюрк. соответствия вроде турецкого samavar, тат. samaur, samuwar являются заимствованиями из русского. Так что слово *самовар* по происхождению исконно русское. Сочетание "сам варит" в соединении со словом "вода" может казаться неправильным. Но всего лишь сто лет назад слово "варить" употреблялось не только в отношении еды (варить суп, рыбу), но и применительно к воде, наравне со словом "кипятить". Более того, в самоварах не только кипятили воду, но и варили пищу и сбитни.

Comment: Опять вы меня опередили, да еще с таким подробным анализом ;)
По поводу "варить". Все правильно, но можно проще. Одной цитатой.

Вот, коль хочешь ты жениться  
И красавцем учиниться, -  
Ты без платья, налегке,  
Искупайся в молоке;  
Тут побудь в воде вареной,  
А потом еще в студеной,  
И скажу тебе, отец,  
Будешь знатный молодец!"  
© П.П. Ершов "Конек-горбунок"

Answer (score 0):

Самовар - это "Задорнов наоборот". Авторы этой идеи возводят самовар к шароварам.

А вот с избой сложнее. Древнерусское ис(ь)ба от праславянского jьstъba не подвергается сомнению. Но само это jьstъba не поддаётся однозначной этимологии. Возможно германский или (менее вероятно) романский генезис. Но обе эти версии не до конца следуют фонетическим особенностям заимствований из соответвующих языков. Поэтому возможно всякое. Но вряд ли тюркское, больно уж слово древнее.

Answer (score 0):

В тюркских языках значение "теплыйй дом" переводится как "исбина", где "ис" - теплый, "бина" - строение, дом, здание. "Бина" заимствовано из арабского с сохранением значения перевода. "Исбина" легко воспринимается  русским языком как "избина" без изменения смысла, в котором "изб" воспринимается уже как корень , а "ина" - как увеличивающий суффикс. Последующее словообразование на основе корня "Изб" основывается на изменении суффиксов "-а", "-ушка" и т.п..

По аналогии можно предположить трансформацию тюркского "Юл" - дорога, в русское "Улица", где звук "ю" превращается в привычный для русского звук "у", и "Ул-" воспринимается как корень, а "-ица" - уменьшительный суффикс. Таким образом, значение "улИЦА" по отношению к "Дорога" приобретает ограниченное в пространстве значение с привязкой к населенному пункту.

Следует обратить внимание, что слово "Дорога" - имело значение административно-территориальной единицы в Русском государстве 16-17 вв. на землях башкир, татар и других поволжских народов (Казанский и Уфимский уезды). В местном произношении - "Даруга".  Делились на волости и тюбы. (Современный толковый словарь)

Comment: Где арабы - и где избы?! Иежду ними тысяча лет и пять тысяч верст.
Я уж не говорю, что арабы - ни разу не тюрки, а семиты.

Comment: По татарски, конечно, "бина" - здание, но "дом" - ѳй. "теплым" больше подходит быть ему.  
А что, это сочетание - ис бина - действительно бытовало у тюрков?

Answer (score 0):

Слово "изба" - скорее всего, его этимологию можно объяснить с помощью финно-угорских языков,в частности, с помощью удмуртского языка, в переводе с которого слово "из" означает "камень". Отсюда же возможно происхождение таких слов, как "из-весть","из-умруд". Для отапливания помещений (землянок,полуземлянок, чумов, шалашей) делались примитивные печи типа кострищ, обложенных камнями, которые после угасания самого костра ещё долго отдавали своё тепло нашим аборигенам.

Comment: Простите, Вы относите финно-угорские к тюркским?
Или ваше скорее всего надо понимать как-то иначе?

Comment: "Скорее всего"-понятие расстяжимое.Финно-угорские и тюркские разные языки,но который язык имеет больше взаимных  примесей это ещё вопрс из вопросов?

Comment: Я не про "вопрос вопросов", а про Ваш ответ.

Вопрос был "правда ли изба и самовар" - из  тюркских языков, 
Вы ответили     
  
>Слово "изба" - скорее всего... ".     
  
Так что извольте все-таки объясниться без пространных рассуждений.

Comment: "правда ли изба и самовар..." Думаю что тут тюркизм далёк от этих понятий "изба и самовар". По избе я уже высказал своё мнение, а вот "САМОВАР" имеет винигретоподобное содержание,судите сами-«САМО-ВА-Р имеет два корня, сам, ва, или варить, слово сам, само и варить допустим русские слова,далее идёт "ва". С коми языка слово "ВА" значи вода. Получается что слово "самовар" означает "сам воду варит"-и это истина.

Answer (score 0):

Есть однако в тюркских языках два слова: слово "и" и слово "зба". Оба переводятся как дом. Только последнее, скажем так, устаревшее. Сочетание двух этих слов более близко, на мой взгляд, чем история с отапливаемым помещением, да ещё и с вопросами о появлении звука И.

Comment: К чему "однако"?